# Создание графического окна на странице

Tags: ajax, javascript, php

Требуется выводить окно с информацией, но не то, что предоставляет стандартный window в JS, мне не нужно открывать новое окно браузера, мне требуется прямо на данной странице открывать окно с собственным интерфейсом (на многих сайтах различные предупреждения работают именно так). Например, регистрация и вход на сайте now.ru - там используются именно те окна, которые мне требуется реализовать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Такое, если набор окон ограничен, нетрудно написать и самому, но ввиду того, что есть неплохие готовые решения, лучше использовать их.

Конкретно там используется, как я быстро поглядел, [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/). Есть и другие фреймворки с окошками. Например, [Prototype UI](http://www.prototype-ui.com/). Хотя, как мне кажется, он больше для приложений подходит =) Или вот - [MooLego UI](http://ui.moolego.org/).

Там везде есть примеры, где можно посмотреть, как оно работает.